# when running in system context, can kernel access the u area of process

Tags: unix

> The kernel must also perform certain system-wide tasks such as
>   responding to device interrupts and recomputing process priorities.
>   Such tasks are not performed on behalf of a particular process, and
>   hence are handled in system context (also called interrupt context).
>   When running in system context, the kernel may not access the address
>   space, u area, or kernel stack of the current process. The kernel may
>   not block when executing in system context, since that would block an
>   innocent process. In some situations there may not even be a current
>   process, for example, when all processes are blocked awaiting I/O
>   completion.

When a read the book 《unix internal》, there are a description about process.But the text above confuse me， especially

> When running in system context, the kernel may not access the address
>   space, u area, or kernel stack of the current process. The kernel may
>   not block when executing in system context, since that would block an
>   innocent process

The author use **may not**， did he mean **can not**  or **sometimes can** ?

Comment: Here "may not" means "cannot" (unconditionally).